# Check if Discord bot has slash command permissions in server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I run a bot that is in several thousand Discord servers - until now, its invite link has not included the `application.commands` scope, only `bot`.

I understand that if I want to transition towards Slash Commands, the bot's users will need to re-invite it with the new permissions.

I plan to keep the traditional method of using bot commands for as long as possible, but is it possible to determine whether my bot has `application.commands` permissions whenever a user from a server interacts with it?

My main reason for wanting to do this is so that I can leave a message in the server encouraging them to re-invite the bot so that slash commands can be used.

I'm using `discord.py` and `discord-py-slash-command`.

Answer (score 1):

When using `discord.py 2.0` or any of the many forks, you can do the following:

```
from discord.bot import ApplicationCommandMixin
```

```
bot = commands.Bot()

for guild in bot.guilds:
    try:
        await ApplicationCommandMixin.get_desynced_commands(bot, guild.id)
    except discord.errors.Forbidden:
        print(f"Slash commands are disabled in {guild}")
```

What happens is that it tries to check if a guild's application commands are out of sync. However, if the bot does not have the `application.commands` scope, an error will be raised. By catching the error, we can check if the bot has the scope or not.

Answer (score -5):

you can DM the server owner by using code below

---

```
owner = guild.owner
await owner.send("hi there!")
```

Run the code and it should DM the owner.

Alternatively you can mention in your commands  to switch and use to slash cmds like arcane bot has done

Comment: This doesn't answer my question - I'm looking for a way to actually *detect* whether my bot is capable of using slash commands or not. If it already is able to use slash commands, then there's no need to message the owner of the server or mention it in a reply to *all* servers.

Comment: your bot will be capable of using slash cmds if `applications.commands` are there
more over its impossible to integrate slash commands without re-inviting @scob_

Comment: You're completely not even acknowledging the OP's question or his comment @NxrmqL